# How to make an List of Objects a parameter in a Lamba using C# Expression API

Tags: c#, expression

I'm trying to dynamically create an predicate to pass into a linq where clause. This is for a generic method that takes two list of the same Type and and list of property names to compare.

```cs
void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> oldRecords, List<T> newRecords, List<string> propertiesOfT)
{
    // dynamically build predicate for this
    var notMatch = oldRecords.Where(o => !newRecords.Any(n => n.Prop1 == o.Prop1 && n.Prop2 == o.Prop2)).ToList();

    // do somethind with notMatch

}
```

I would like to convert this:

```cs
var notMatch = oldRecords.Where(o => !newRecords.Any(n => n.Prop1 == o.Prop1 && n.Prop2 == o.Prop2)).ToList();
```

To achieve this:

```cs
var predicate = "n => n.Prop1 == o.Prop1 && n.Prop2 == o.Prop2"; // sudo code
var notMatch = oldRecords.Where(o => !newRecords.Any(predicate));
```

or this

```cs
var predicate = "o => !newRecords.Any(n => n.Prop1 == o.Prop1 && n.Prop2 == o.Prop2)" // sudo code
var notMatch = oldRecords.Where(predicate);
```

How do I populate newRecords when dynamically creating the Expression?
And how would I reference parameter o and parameter n in the Expresssion.

I've gotten this far:

```cs
//construct the two parameters
var o = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
var n = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "n");

// How to I go about populating o with values and n with values
// from oldRecords and newRecords? or is that no neccessary

var property = Expression.Property(o, typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").Name);

var value = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType("12345", typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").PropertyType), typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").PropertyType);

BinaryExpression binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, property, value);
```

Any sudo code or clue where to look to achieve this?

Comment: Will it always be an equal compare ?

Comment: Yes it will always be an equal compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reflection it's quite easy. You just to have to think about it. Here's the working version.

```
void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> oldRecords, List<T> newRecords, List<string> propertiesOfT)
{
    // get the list of property to match
    var properties = propertiesOfT.Select(prop => typeof(T).GetProperty(prop)).ToList();


    // Get all old record where we don't find any matching new record where all the property equal that old record
    var notMatch = oldRecords.Where(o => !newRecords.Any(n => properties.All(prop => prop.GetValue(o).Equals(prop.GetValue(n))))).ToList();            
}
```

And here's a sample set i tried and it works

```
public class test
{
    public int id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string desc { get; set; } = "";
    public test(string s, int i)
    {
        desc = s;id = i;
    }
}

private void Main()
{
    var oldRecords = new List<test>()
    {
        new test("test",1),
        new test("test",2)
    };

    var newRecords = new List<test>()
    {
        new test("test1",1),
        new test("test",2)
    };

    SomeMethod(oldRecords, newRecords, new List<string>() { "id", "desc" });
}
```

Comment: Great answer and solution. It solved my problem. Can this also be done using System.Linq.Expressions Expression Class? I'm asking because I'm trying to learn more about Expression class.

Comment: @oldditty I never had a single case that i needed to use the `Expression` class so far. So i never bother to learn how it works.

Comment: if this is the accepted answer then it looks odd, in the sense of the generic types which are both of type T. could be completely wrong, but are you even using the  generic part if they both are the same type. could the generics  be taken out. Also could you use `PropertyInfo[] arrayPropertyInfos = T.GetType().GetProperties();`, to get the props?

Comment: @Seabizkit Yes it's sound odd as if he knows the actual properties he knows the object already but i am guessing that he has classes that should be inherited and he did not do it and have many base class with exact same properties and want to do the same filter. He obviously has hardcoded stuff somewhere before this method call.

Comment: The last parameter propertiesOfT actually form a composite key for the type T where T are models for tables in an old existing database. The composite key properties are determined by their model configuration files.

Comment: @oldditty You need to override the `Equals` in your class. They was no workaround this anyhow. The other solution was to implement custom comparer for each class which turns out pretty much the same kind of code.